# Hashing torrent file pieces

Tags: c#, bittorrent

I am trying to calculate and compare torrent file pieces hashes and have run into a problem where based on my files i get more hashes then in torrent file generated by torrent applications.

I have a hashing function to calculate hashes of the file pieces and each file goes through it

```
      public static async Task<IEnumerable<byte[]>> CreateHashTableAsync(HashAlgorithm provider,
        Stream inputStream,
        int blockSize,
        IBufferManager bufferManager,
        CancellationToken ct)
    {
        if (provider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(provider));

        if (inputStream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputStream));

        if (bufferManager == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bufferManager));

        var HASH_TABLE = new List<byte[]>();

        var BUFFER = bufferManager.TakeBuffer(blockSize);

        int CALL_READ = 0;
        while ((CALL_READ = await inputStream.ReadAsync(BUFFER, 0, blockSize, ct).ConfigureAwait(false)) > 0)
        {                
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var BLOCK_HASH = provider.ComputeHash(BUFFER, 0, CALL_READ);
            HASH_TABLE.Add(BLOCK_HASH);
        }

        BUFFER = null;

        return HASH_TABLE;

    }
```

As i said the problem is that at the end of hashing of all files i have a little more pieces than in torrent file.
Should i handle the hashing differently ?
I understand that at the end of the file its common that the data remaining in file is less than the piece size but not sure how this situation should be handled.

Comment: Your `List<byte[]>` is *not* a "hash table". Also, it is not idiomatic C# to use `UPPER_CASE` identifiers, which are normally used in C and C++ to denote preprocessor macros and constants, but you're using them for variables.

Comment: thank you for noting that but how does it relate to original question ?

Comment: It doesn't relate to your actual question, but I provided it as an otherwise helpful comment.

Comment: To be honest indeed for some strange reason it started to have the local variables with caps, it helps me separate the locals from input variables. Is that such a bad thing to do ? :)

Comment: I argue it is a bad thing to do when other people encounter your code because the vast majority of C# programmers comply with the convention to use `camelCase` for both method parameters and local variables. C# only uses `UPPER_CASE` identifiers for preprocessor `#define` and `#if` symbols - so you'll only end-up confusing other people who read your code.

Comment: true, need to change my manners :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a correct approach:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Piece 0         | Piece 1         | Piece 2         | Piece 3         |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| File A                   | File B                        | <- file B does not end at the end of piece 3
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

This would be an incorrect approach:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Piece 0         | Piece 1         | Piece 2         | Piece 3         |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| File A                   |00000000| File B                        |000| 
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Yes indeed i suspected that, so in such cases where there is an overlap i would need to fill the hash byte array with data from the first file and then the next and only then execute hash function on it ?
e.g piece size 1024 bytes 1000 bytes from first and 24 bytes from next , then execute hash ?

Comment: Yes, imagine the torrent data (regardless of the number of files in it) as a continues array of bytes in the same order as specified in the torrent info file.

Comment: You will also have to pay special attention to his when persisting downloaded pieces locally or when responding to a piece request from a remote peer, meaning you might will have to save the bytes from a piece to more than one file or read bytes to a piece from multiple files.

Comment: You're welcome. I've also noticed you're rigorously testing your method inputs which is always a good thing to do. If you'd like to make your job a bit easier and faster you might want to check out Defensive Programming Framework at https://github.com/aljazsim/defensive-programming-framework-for-net.

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect assumption on this line:

```
(CALL_READ = await inputStream.ReadAsync(BUFFER, 0, blockSize, ct)
```

`Stream.Read` does not guarantee that `blockSize`-many bytes will actually be read, you should check to see if `CALL_READ == blockSize` after the call to `ReadAsync` completes and if it doesn't then you should handle that case specifically.

Comment: holly molly you right that could be it, let me correct that and see if it resolves the problem